# UI Design:How to set TextField text invisible while i am entering text into TextField

Tags: ios, passwords, uitextfield

I have one TextField in my storyBoard and that TextField is for enter password. I want while i am entering password(text) into that TextField, text should not be visible. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,IF you don't want to display anything on the textfield But it should get capture

```
[textField.text setTextColor:BackGround_color_Of_Your_View];// Just Doing Fake
```

OR `[textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];` To Set as like *****

Answer (score 2):

You have in the Attributes inspector, under the `Text Field` section a check box named `Secure`.

Or programmatically, you can do :

```
[myTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Comment: Yep, setting the secure property to YES will let you see **** instead of what's really typed.

Answer (score 0):

**Using xib** `Your Project --->  select textfield ---> go to Attribute Inspector -->check mark for Secure option` to hide your text

**Programatically** --- `yourtextFieldname.secureTextEntry = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textColor to clearColor.